# Server response to ajax call with 200 but on browser I get error 400 on Safari

Tags: ajax, wordpress, safari, httpresponse, cloudflare

I have a strange behavior on a WordPress site. It is working just fine but several users (on safari) reported seeing error 400. While testing with safari I manage to reproduce the problem with changing the user-agent of the browser. Then I started getting error 400 on each ajax call. I've checked the `access.log` and all request to admin-ajax.php where served with status 200. But when I check the inspector in Safari, the same ajax request got status 400. And this is happening with each and every single ajax request on every page of the site. I've tried to log out/log in, cleared all cookies, cache and etc. but the error was still there.
The site uses ClouldFlare, so I went there and checked all the security and firewall rules, I didn't found my IP blocked anywhere.

So now the question is how a response with code 200 becomes 400?

Here is also the request and response of ajax call:

```
Summary

URL: https://www.example.com.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
Status: 400
Source: Local Override
Address: yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy:zzz
Initiator: some-script.min.js:1:2080

Request

:method: POST
:scheme: https
:authority: www.example.com.com
:path: /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Origin: https://www.example.com.com
Cookie: some-cookies
Content-Length: 88
Accept-Language: en-us
Host: www.example.com.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.3 Safari/605.1.15
Referer: https://www.example.com.com/units/main/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive

Response

:status: 400
Date: Wed, 27 Jan 2021 12:27:47 GMT
Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0, no-store
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Type: text/html
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: some-cookies
Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.example.com.com
cf-edge-cache: cache,platform=wordpress
expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
nel: {"max_age":604800,"report_to":"cf-nel"}
report-to: {"group":"cf-nel","endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report?s=some-token"}],"max_age":604800}
cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC
cf-request-id: 07e569767900001c377fb67000000001
cf-ray: 618278372fc81c37-SOF
x-robots-tag: noindex
Server: cloudflare

Request Data

MIME Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
action: my_ajax_callback
term_id: 1209
page_id
```

And this is the from the `access.log`:

`xx.xxx.xx.xxx - - [24/Mar/2021:10:16:46 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.0" 200 12203 "https://example.com/some-page/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.3 Safari/605.1.15"`

**UPDATE**

I have to say that this is happening only on Safari and no other browser. Also I'm running Safari in VM with Mojave, not sure if this is related, but I though it is worthy to mention this.

I have tried to pause the CF service, and this change was visible on all other browsers but Safari continued to server the site over CF (I can see in the response header `server` that its value was `cloudflare` while on the other browsers it was `nginx`). I've flushed the DNS in the terminal and restarted VM a few times but this didn't changed.

I have also disabled all the security and firewall features on CloudFlare after I enabled it again but this also didn't solve the problem. I'm starting to believe that the problem lies some where in Safari and not in CF.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning Cloudflare off, the setting is called "Pause Cloudflare on Site" to isolate it and see if that makes a difference. Maybe you have some goofy modsec rules in place?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that yesterday (and today as well) with no luck. All other browsers changed the response header `server` from `cloudflare` to `nginx` but Safari didn't. I tried to delete the DNS cache for the OS (Mojave)  and the browser cache, I've restarted the machine several times but it still hit cloudflare and returned 400.